# confusion using regex

Tags: java, regex

If i want to use regex to find either "<" or ">" within a string and split the string based on either "<" or ">", how would i do that?

for instance i may have a string that looks like this:

```
String str = <name> hello bob, how are you today </name>
```

i found these two links, but i still feel confused:
[link 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) 
[link 2](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: string splitting twice... once through on ">" and then converted it back into a string... and then split again on "<" but that failed... it's not what i want..not familiar with regex

Comment: And what exactly are you confused about? Take your time and learn regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split("[<>]");`

The brackets means you'll match any characters inside them.

Comment: thanks, i just realized so any character i want to search for can be placed between "[ ]" and if i want to search for a range i can use "-" thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement `or` in a regex:

1. Alternation using the `|` operator:

   - `a|b` means "`a` or `b`".
   - any sub-regex can be on either side of the `|`: `one|two.*three` means "`one` or (`two`, followed by any string, followed by `three`)".
   - you might need to enclose the alternation in parentheses to limit the scope of the alternation: `^(one|two.*three)$`
2. Character classes:

   - `[ab]` means "one character out of the collection `ab`".
   - Inversion is possible: `[^ab]` means "any character except `a` or `b`".
   - Ranges are supported: `[a-b]` means "any character from the collection `abc`".

So in your case, a possible regex would be `(<|>)` or `[<>]`, where the latter is preferred since both alternatives are exactly one character in length.

To split a string, you can use the `.split()` method:

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("[<>]")
```